# dictsort gives no resuts

Tags: django, django-templates

I use a queryset `fields` in 2 places on my view.

One is ordered by another field, the other is ordered by facet.  I'd like to order the dataset in 2 ways on the page, rather than passing the queryset twice.

I am trying to use [dictsort](http://%7B%25%20for%20book%20in%20books%7Cdictsort:%22author.age%22%20%25%7D) to do this as is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540032/sorting-related-items-in-a-django-template) and a few other questions.

I have this in my code:

```
{% for field in fields|dictsort:"facet_order" %}
    field.facet_order
{% endfor %}
```

But i see nothing rendered.

The loop works fine without the `dictsort`, and as a sanity check i have run the below with no problem:

```
{% for field in fields %}
    field.facet_order
{% endfor %}
```

It yields:

```
None None None None 1 0 None ...
```

My code looks to me like it strongly resembles django's documentation example below:

```
{% for book in books|dictsort:"author.age" %}
    * {{ book.title }} ({{ book.author.name }})
{% endfor %}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, i had to register a custom template function as outlined in the answer i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238939/sorting-objects-in-template)

I did this by following djangos example outlined [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout):

```
# Add templatetags/poll_extras.py
polls/
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        poll_extras.py


# Inside templatetags/poll_extras.py
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def sort_by(queryset, order):
    return queryset.order_by(order)


# in the template:
{% load poll_extras %}
```